# Nifi - Converting previously saved now() in attribute

Tags: apache-nifi, minify

I use UpdateAttribute to check timings of slow processors. First UpdateAttribute has `DATA_START ${now()}`, while the second one has `DATA_STOP ${now()}` attribute. Slow processor is placed between the two.

I've been trying to convert `DATA_START` to a number, so I could calculate the time difference.

`${now():toNumber():minus(${DATA_START:toNumber()}):format("HH:mm:ss")}`

This doesn't work, unfortunately. The issue is in this part `${DATA_START:toNumber()}`. NiFi couldn't convert previously saved `now()` into a number.

I have a lot of timers in my flow, so adding new attributes that will contain `${now():toNumber()}` would be troublesome.

Is there any way to apply `toNumber()` to a previously saved `now()`?

Various types of `format` and `toDate()` didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but it looks like a hack

`${now():toNumber():minus(${DATA_START:format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):toDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):toNumber()}):divide(1000)}`

For some reason, NiFi doesn't think that previously saved `now()` is a Data. I convert it to a String, then convert it back to a Date, and in the end, I could get a timestamp. Timestamps can be manipulated and that's what I need.

`${DATA_START:format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):toDate('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'):toNumber()}`

Comment: Its not a hack if it works?  HAHA Seriously though converting to timestamp in nifi is creating a string attribute not a timestamp data type value...  you are fighting against that, so you need to convert back to number, do math, then back to string...

Answer (score 1):

@Alex  Why don't you store the raw values and use them for your difference check?  Converting to human readable format can still be done if you need both.  Solution is to just create 2 attributes instead of one.

```
DATA_START_RAW = ${now()}

DATA_START_FORMATED = ${now():toNumber():format("HH:mm:ss")}
```

I do suspect you just did not find the right expression language.  This can be tricky sometimes, especially with formatted timestamps and "math"...

One other suggestion:  do not OVERCHECK flow performance in the flow.  This is not really a best practices concept.  I do not know your use case, and I am a true advocate that NiFi can do anything. I have created many flows in production and have never checked flow timing within the flow.

Comment: I have a few exceptionally slow processors that work with external APIs and Databases. I use timings mainly to find these bottlenecks.
Adding second attribute is an option that would take some time to implement.